# проблема с отображением

Tags: javascript, php, html

Пытаюсь сделать IP-логер. Работает, но отображает в браузере так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Заголовок страницы</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<p>IP-адрес сохранен</p>

<?php
echo
$file="log.txt";
$data=date("d.m.Y");
$time=date("H:i");
$ip=trim($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$agent=trim($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if(is_file($file)){
$fo=fopen($file,"a");
$res="$data|$time|$ip|$agent n";
$fw=fputs($fo,$res);
fclose($fo);
print"";
}
else{
print"";
}
?>

<p><img src="images/logo.png" width="300" height="226" border="0"></p>
<br>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: в корневом .htaccess задайте кодировку `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`

Comment: Всё html файлы должны начинаться с `<!DOCTYPE html>` но да это проблема с кодировкой.